# How do I import and symbolicate a crash report on this Xcode 6.3.1?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, crash-reports

How do I import crashes log on this Xcode 6.3? I have zero crashes on apple servers for all my apps, or I am a programmer genius and my apps have zero crashes or something is not working on Xcode (surprise!).

Anyway, a customer sent me a crash log from one of my apps for Mac, but I don't see how this crash log can be imported on this new amazing Xcode 6.3?

Any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by "import"?

Comment: I have a crash report file. On older versions I dragged that file on a device and voilà!

Comment: Just as a FYI, the "App Analytics" in iTunes Connect, is only for iOS/tvOS. I asked a Apple engineer at WWDC why there were no stats for my (OSX) apps, and he told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head on the wall, I see that, thanks to Apple, it is now impossible to symbolicate crash logs from files. It was possible on previous versions of Xcode, but not on 6.3. Apple removed that functionality.

Comment: Please tell me this isn't still the case! I've just got a crash log and can't connect to the device, and it's not in App Analytics

Comment: This is why I refer to Apple as Crapple sometimes. They remove features but their documentation doesn't get updated. I was getting so frustrated dragging the file over from Finder.

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me:

> If you plug in /any/ device then select the device in the Devices window and click View Device Logs, you should be able to drag the crash report into the resulting sheet.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11473

Comment: This also worked for me, but I'm shocked this what you're forced to do :(

Answer (score 2):

So far I only have the command line script that attempts to symbolicate crashlog files automatically:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DEVELOPER_DIR=$(xcode-select --print-path) # set the developer dir, this will be used by the symbolicator script
SYMBOLICATOR=($(find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name "symbolicatecrash")) #find the symbolicatecrash script from Xcode
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )" 
mdimport "/dSymFiles" #<-- put folder of your stored dsym files here

while true; do
    for i in $DIR/*.crash; do # for all crash logs, case sensitive extension        
        sudo chmod 777 $i
        o="$i".txt

        if [ $i -nt $o ]
        then
            echo "Symbolicate $i"
            perl $SYMBOLICATOR -o $o $i
        fi 
    done    
    sleep 1 
done
```

You can put the crashlogs (*.crash) into the same folder as this script. Also remove spaces and other weirdo cr
I didn't find a suitable way for "manually" symbolicating a crashlog using Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own crash report file you want to import into Xcode, you still have to do it the old (flawed) way.

Edit: I just saw that you said Mac apps.  You should be able to select your Mac from the left pane in the Devices window instead of plugging in an iOS device.

- Go to Window -> Devices and plug in an iOS device using your USB
  cable.
- Select the device from the left pane Select the "View Device
  Logs" button
- Select "All Logs" from the top of the left pane Drag
  your crash report to the left pane, to the list of crash reports.
- You will see a green + sign show up. Wait a few minutes and it should
  be there and symbolicated.

Sometimes I've had to force the list to refresh by leaving the page and going back or selecting a different crash report.

Comment: Thanks but like I said this is the crash of a Mac app. There is no "view device logs" button. Your instructions probably work for iOS devices but not for macs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workflow for using the command-line to symbolicate crashes. It works on Xcode 12.3 and macOS 10.15.7. I'm symbolicating a desktop app so for me it doesn't work to use the Devices and Simulators window in Xcode (at least I couldn't figure it out), but I think this workflow is most universal, eg it works even if someone just sends a screenshot of the crash window!

First, you'll need a folder with the app and the symbols; eg, create a folder (eg app) and copy into it the application (eg MyApp.app) and the .app.dSYM package (eg MyApp.app.dSYM). Both are available in the Xcode archive (if the symbols are included in the build settings): Xcode > Organizer > right-click the archive > Show in Finder > right-click xarchive file > Show Package Contents, find the mentioned files.

The crash log has backtraces with these columns:
stack #, binary image name, address, load address, line offset (I think), eg

> 0   MyApp                            0x102d2e106 0x102d0b000 +
> 143622

To get the symbol for that line, use the `atos` command, passing in the binary executable of your app, the architecture of the crash log, the load address, and the address(es) to symbolicate, eg:

```
atos -o app/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -arch x86_64 -l 0x102d0b000 0x102d2e106
```

A useful tip is if you leave off the address (last parameter), `atos` will read the addresses from the prompt, so just paste them in and press enter. Alternatively, you can add several addresses to the end of the `atos` command (with spaces) and the command will print out the lines.

To get the arch string, look for **arch** in the crash log below the stacktraces and pick the record whose name matches binary image name in the stacktrace. If you leave it off it assumes it's the same architecture as the computer. For iPhone and iPad I believe it is **arm64**, Intel is **x86_64**, and I don't know what to put for Apple Silicon. From the man page:

> It is possible to get symbols for addresses from a different machine architecture than the system on which atos is running.  For example, when running atos on an Intel-
> based system, one may wish to get the symbol for an address that came from a backtrace of a process running on an ARM device.  To do so, use the -arch flag to specify the
> desired architecture (such as i386 or arm) and pass in a corresponding symbol-rich Mach-O binary image file with a binary image of the corresponding architecture (such as
> a Universal Binary).

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report#Symbolicate-the-Crash-Report-with-the-Command-Line

And also use `man atos`